# wxWidgets + OpenCV: wxBitmap does not draw wxImage correctly

Tags: c++, opencv, wxwidgets

I'm trying to make a `wxImage` out of a `cv::Mat` raw data, and have a `wxBitmap` draw it out on a `wxPanel`-derived class (this `bmImage` class).

Here's the code for loading the `cv::Mat` data into the `wxImage`.

```
cv::Mat asCvMat = cv::imread("something.png", 1);
cv::imshow("preview", asCvMat);
cv::Mat cvtResult;
aswxImage = wxImage(asCvMat.cols, asCvMat.rows, asCvMat.data, true);
wxLogMessage(wxT("%s"), std::string((char*)asCvMat.data));
```

And here's the code for drawing the `wxBitmap` out.

```
void bmImage::render(wxDC& dc) {
    wxBitmap bitmap = wxBitmap(aswxImage);
    dc.DrawBitmap(bitmap, wxPoint(0, 0), false);
}
```

[image]

The little image on the left is the image I try to load and showed with `cv::imshow`, and the one on the right is the resulting `wxBitmap`. It doesn't show the image correctly. How should I fix this to show the image properly?

Plus, what's confusing me is the (null) value of `asCvMat.data`. Does this mean that `wxImage()` has finished loading all the pixel data from it so it has reached the end (`\0`)?

***EDIT***

```
cv::Mat asCvMat = cv::imread("something.png", 1);
cv::imshow("preview", asCvMat);
void *mdata = malloc((size_t)(asCvMat.dataend - asCvMat.datastart));
std::memcpy(mdata, asCvMat.data, (size_t)(asCvMat.dataend - asCvMat.datastart));

cv::Mat cvtResult;
aswxImage = wxImage(asCvMat.cols, asCvMat.rows, (unsigned char*)mdata, false);

wxLogMessage(wxT("%s"), std::string((char*)mdata));
```

yet it's the same thing... sometimes it throws an unhandled memory exception if I load a large image.

Comment: the data from asCvMat will get deleted, when asCvMat goes out of scope. so your aswxImage  probably has invalid pointer. please read up in the wx docs, who should be responsible for keeping the data

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `cv::Mat` data is in the format expected by `wxImage`, i.e. simple RGB without any interleave?

Also, how exactly do you call `render()`? You can't/shouldn't call it directly, is it called from your wxEVT_PAINT handler?

Comment: The data is in the format expected (I tried `wxFrame::saveFile()` and it reproduced the same image); `render()` is called by a `wxEVT_PAINT` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by:

```
sizer_to_contain_image->Add(image, 1, wxEXPAND);
```

and:

```
sizer_containing_image->SetSizeHints(frame_containing_sizer);
```